# Is there a better way of telling a function to get all fields when it can also accept the exact field names to get as an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that reads from mysql database.

```js
// ['username', 'full_name', 'dob', 'add_line1', 'add_line2', 'city', 'state', 'country']
const allUserFields = require('../fields/user'); 

const readUser = async (filter, fields) => {
  let fieldsToRead; // *
  if (fields.length > 0 && fields[0] === 'all') {  // *
    fieldsToRead = allUserFields // *
  } else { // *
    fieldsToRead = fields; // *
  } // *

  // This is another function that takes the filter, 
  // turns that into a statement and params list, runs the query and returns the result
  const rows = await getRows('user', filter, fieldsToRead); // getRows(tableName, filter, fields);
  return rows[0];
}
```

When I want only the dob and city of a user whose username is amigo, I use it like:

```js
const user = await readUser({username: 'amigo'}, ['dob', 'city']);
```

When I want all the fields, I do:

```js
const user = await readUser({username: 'amigo'}, ['all']);
```

I don't want to import the array of all fields in each file in which I want to read all the fields of the user and pass it.

Hence the lines marked with * are written.

Questions:

1. I was wondering if there was a better way of indicating to the function to get all fields instead of passing `['all']`?
2. Also what term do we use for such problems? Like we say 'ds algo problem' when ther question is related to ds and algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`['all']` means reading a single column named "all", nothing else. You need some out-of-band value to convey the meaning of "*I don't specify anything, just read everything*". An empty array `[]` can suffice for this, as it rarely makes sense to read no columns (although for insert/delete statements, it might mean "*I don't want any result*"). Instead, I would suggest passing no array at all and have it default to "all columns" in that case. This also lends itself to very simple code using default parameters:

```
async function readUser(filter, fields = allUserFields) {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  return (await getRows('user', filter, fields))[0];
}
```

Comment: Passing no array at all sounds good, I can modify the function to read all fields when the passed `fields` parameter is not an array. Sometimes there are additional parameters after the fields in similar functions that I have written. In those cases I would have to pass `null` explictly, which didn't seem intuitive either as I try to not store different datatypes in same variable. But I guess in this case I can't have both, `['all']` is misleading, I may have to go with `null`. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have lots of parameters, use an options object instead, which makes it easy to omit properties again. Passing `null` is fine as well, but notice only `undefined` leads to the parameter default applying. Yes, if you don't want to go with the empty array, you need to pass something that is not an array. There's nothing wrong with that, JavaScript is dynamically typed exactly to allow such kind of overloading.